# Calculating $\hat{x}^2$ and $\hat{p}^2$ - harmonic oscillator matrix form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

In harmonic oscillator, we can write $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ as (I obtained the $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ by using matrix form of the ladder operators) ;

$$\hat{x} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 
                            \sqrt{1} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
             \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\hat{p} = i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 
                            \sqrt{1} & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
             \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I need to find $\hat{x}^2$ and $\hat{p}^2$. My approach was to do simple matrix multiplication

$$\hat{x}^2 = \frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 
                            \sqrt{1} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
             \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 
                            \sqrt{1} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
             \end{bmatrix}$$

so

$$\hat{x}^2 = \frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
                            \sqrt{2} & 0 & 2
             \end{bmatrix}$$

and similarly

$$\hat{p}^2 = \frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\ 
                            0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
                            -\sqrt{2} & 0 & 2
             \end{bmatrix}$$

But this feels somewhat wrong, and when I do the same procedures for ($4\times4$) $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ matrices, I obtain wrong results.

I have also tried to perform the same operations by using
$$\hat{x}^2 = a_{+}a_{+} + a_{+}a_{-} + a_{-}a_{+} + a_{-}a_{-}$$ but I got the same result.

Are $\hat{x}^2$ and $\hat{p}^2$ correct ?

Comment: In what basis are these $3 \times 3$ matrices expressed? The three lowest energy levels?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I obtained the $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ by using matrix form of the ladder operators.

Comment: Check-my-work questions are off-topic.

Comment: @seVenVo1d This does not make sense. Mathematical rigor aside, the ladder operators are infinite matrices; in no way you can obtain $x$ and $p$ as finite matrices.

Comment: But that is what is given in the book..there's even questions like that

Comment: @TobiasFünke See stephen gasiorowicz quantum physics chapter 9 problems from 1-6

Comment: @TobiasFünke How can I approach to the problem then ?

Comment: Well, check the existent answer... I don't have the book, so I cannot cross-check. $X$ and $P$ are operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space (do you know why?) - thus, they cannot be represented by $n\times n$ matrices for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I can understand your point. I am also confused. That's kind of why I asked the question

Comment: As for now, your question is off-topic as it is a check-my-work question and it'll be closed, I guess. You can consider to rephrase the question appropriately, e.g. with a quote from the book you cite and to explicitly state your confusion regarding principles instead of concrete computations.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I see...but also I figured out the reason, thanks to Christophe. It seems that I was truncated matrices and taking the square which turns out the be wrong obviously..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple check is to compute the Hamiltonian
$$H={p^2\over 2m}+{1\over 2}m\omega^2x^2$$
With your matrices, you get
$$H={\hbar\omega\over 4}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & -\sqrt 2 \cr 0 & 3 & 0 \cr -\sqrt 2 & 0 & 2}+{\hbar\omega\over 4}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & \sqrt 2 \cr 0 & 3 & 0 \cr \sqrt 2 & 0 & 2}={\hbar\omega\over 2}\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 3 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 2}$$
The Hamiltonian is diagonal as expected with the matrix elements ${1\over 2}\hbar\omega$, ${3\over 2}\hbar\omega$ and $\hbar\omega$. The last one is wrong but it is due to the fact that you truncated the $x$ and $p$ matrices to a finite subspace of the Hilbert space. With $4\times 4$ matrices, this term would be correct but then the last (fourth) one would then be wrong.

Comment: Is this something expected?

Comment: @seVenVo1d Yes, the error on the last component disappears when you work on the infinite-dimensional Fock space instead of the truncated one.

Comment: But when I truncate and perform the operations my answer and the books do not match for $(4\times4)$ matrices.

Comment: I guess that your book gives the true $x^2$ matrix truncated to $4\times 4$. You first truncated $x$ and then took its square. That’s where comes the discrepancy.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the reason..thanks a lot for pointing that out